# UITableViewController shiver issue while scrolling

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode, ios7, ios8

I have a `UITableViewController` called `SignUpViewController`. It conatains multiple `UITextField`s to enter Username, password, etc. So when user click on the textfield, then tableview should scroll above keyboard for the visibility of clicked textfield. Its working perfectly. It scrolls correctly. But my issues is while scrolling all textfields shivering.

Note :

When I set this `UITableViewController` as rootview controller then there is no textfield Shivering...

My code is :

```
FAERegistrationTableViewController *registerView;//(declared in interface)

 registerView = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:KstoryBoardIDRegistration];
    [registerView setDelegatePressBack:self];
    [self addChildViewController:registerView];
    [self.view addSubview:registerView.view];
    registerView.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, registerView.view.frame.size.width,  registerView.view.frame.size.height);
```

Comment: Check viewcontroller containment properly. DidMoveToParentViewController is missing.